# removing objects from an object array in php?

Tags: php

for example say i have an object array called $list looks like this:

```
<(stdClass)#16 (3) {
  ["1"]=>
  <(8) "50504496"
  ["2"]=>
  <(8) "12435374"
  ["3"]=>
  <(8) "12436374"
```

Im doing a foreach on the object array and removing them if they exist in the database i.e

```
   foreach($list as $l){

    //do the query

    if( it exists){
      //remove from objects: this is where i need help!!
      }
   }
```

i have the db logic, im just stuck to know how i can remove objects, i was thinking maybe i should create a new object and add them thier. thanks
    }

Comment: `unset` [php.net/unset](http://li.php.net/unset)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use: unset

```
foreach($list as $key => $obj){
  if( exists .. ) {
      unset($list[$key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks brillant answer, what deos ... stand for is it 1,2 or 3 $var names

Answer (score 0):

run your query and if it returns `>0` number of rows then you have a result, use `unset($object->$var)` to unset a variable

Answer (score 0):

Try like:

```
    foreach($list as $li)
    {
        if($li)
        {
            //copy into another array.
        }
    }
```

i thnk its may simple

Comment: how can i copy into another array?

Answer (score 0):

Try like:
        $i=0;

```
  foreach($list as $li)
  {
      if($li)
      {
          $b[i] = $li;
          $i++;
      }
   }
```

array '$b' will hold the values in $list which are not null